# I am trying to make this function into a 1D array and a plot

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot

How can I use this function to create a 1D array for the yearly amount. For example, I want the array to have all the elements as the yearly amounts for the number of years the user inputed.
The last couple lines are meant to be doing that but I get the error "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (60,) and (5,)"

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
years=float(input("Please enter the amount of years to calculate for:"))  # taking input from key board i.e number of years
current_balance=1000.0 # now current fund is 1000


def interest_amount(p):  # creating function to find monthly intrest
    interest=(p*0.5*1)/1200 # formula to find intrest i.e(PTR)/100
    # RETURNING INTEREST BACK
    return interest    


years=years*12.0

storebal=[] # EMPTY LIST TO STORE YEARLY AMOUNT
count=1
c=0.0

for i in range(1,int(years)+1):


    interest=interest_amount(current_balance) # CALLING FUNCTION
    
    current_balance=current_balance+interest+200.0
    if count==12:
        count=0
        storebal.append(current_balance-200.0)
        
    if c==years:
         break
    count+=1
year=1    
for e in storebal: # DISPLAY YEARLY SAVED AMOUNT
    
    print(F'{year}-Year: $'+"{:.2f}".format(e))
    year+=1
x = np.arange(1,int(years)+1)
plt.plot(x, storebal)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are converting your years into months by multiplying them by 12, then trying to plot them on a yearly axis. You can resolve this by changing your variable name to months, instead of years.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
years=float(input("Please enter the amount of years to calculate for:"))  # taking input from key board i.e number of years
current_balance=1000.0 # now current fund is 1000


def interest_amount(p):  # creating function to find monthly intrest
    interest=(p*0.5*1)/1200 # formula to find intrest i.e(PTR)/100
    # RETURNING INTEREST BACK
    return interest    


months=years*12.0 # variable name months
storebal=[] # EMPTY LIST TO STORE YEARLY AMOUNT
count=1

# i is not necessary as you do not use it
# the break condition is also unnecessary as you do not increment c
for _ in range(1,int(months)+1): #use months instead of years
    interest=interest_amount(current_balance) # CALLING FUNCTION
    
    current_balance=current_balance+interest+200.0
    if count==12:
        count=0
        storebal.append(current_balance-200.0)
    count+=1

year=1    
for e in storebal: # DISPLAY YEARLY SAVED AMOUNT
    print(F'{year}-Year: $'+"{:.2f}".format(e))
    year+=1

x = np.arange(1,int(years)+1)
plt.plot(x, storebal)
plt.show()
```

This code should produce the results you are looking for.